# More than one instance of Stimulus Application

Tags: stimulusjs

Is it possible to have more than one instance of a Stimulus Application on a single page?

e.g.

```
const a = Application.start()
a.register('controller-a', ControllerA);

const b = Application.start()
b.register('controller-b', ControllerB);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Each Stimulus application instance can have its own root element it targets and its own schema.

There's nothing stopping you from creating multiple applications. However, just make sure that's what you want to do. It's usually simpler to just have one.

See https://stimulus.hotwired.dev/handbook/installing#overriding-attribute-defaults

Also note that if you use the same identifier in both applications, it will work but each controller must implement the same method names. Assuming you are using actions to call methods, otherwise you will get a console error advising that the method doesn't exist.